# django detail page is not linking to detail page id

Tags: django

blog.html

```
<a href="/detail/{{ detail.id }}/" class="text-dark">{{ cmccDemo.summary }}</a>
```

url.py

```
path('detail/<int:id>/', cmccDemos.views.detail, name='detail'),
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, id=None):
    cmccDemo_detail = get_object_or_404(CmccDemo, id=id)
    return render(request, 'cmccDemos/detail.html', {'cmccDemo': cmccDemo_detail})
```

But when i click the blog for detail it direct me to url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail//`
When I manually put `http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/1/` it works.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the issue

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' cmccDemo.id %}" class="text-dark">{{ cmccDemo.summary }}</a>
```

Comment: The blog page even not working now: NoReverseMatch at /blog/
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['detail/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']